# Get the current classname in Android?

Tags: android

When I use className I can't get the current value, the right value is "com.github.shadowsocks.Shadowsocks". My code is below.

```
  List<ApplicationInfo> apps;
    apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(GET_SIGNATURES);
 for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++) {
        if (apps.get(i).packageName.equals("com.github.shadowsocks")) {
            tvShow.append("\n" + apps.get(i).backupAgentName);
            tvShow.append("\n" + apps.get(i).className);
            tvShow.append("\n" + apps.get(i).dataDir);
            tvShow.append("\n" + apps.get(i).deviceProtectedDataDir);
            tvShow.append("\n" + apps.get(i).manageSpaceActivityName);
            tvShow.append("\n" + apps.get(i).nativeLibraryDir);
            tvShow.append("\n" + apps.get(i).permission);
            tvShow.append("\n" + apps.get(i).processName);
            tvShow.append("\n" + apps.get(i).publicSourceDir);
            tvShow.append("\n" + apps.get(i).sourceDir);
            tvShow.append("\n" + apps.get(i).taskAffinity);
            tvShow.append("\n" + apps.get(i).toString());
            tvShow.append("\n" + apps.get(i).name);
            tvShow.append("\n" + apps.get(i).packageName);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `this.getClass().getCanonicalName()`

Comment: thank you, but I need the apk's classname, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

From comments I think you want APK's package name. Snippet below will return apk's package name :

```
context.getApplicationInfo().packageName
```

OR

```
context.getPackageName()
```

Comment: thank you! but it is still output applicationinfo's classname